# Improving ordinal ranking

Tags: algorithm, statistics, ranking, scoring

I'm trying to improve an ordinal ranking implementation we are currently using to determine a unique ranking amongst competitors over a set of tasks.

The problem is as follows. There are K tasks and N competitors. All of the tasks are equally important. For each of the tasks, the competitors perform the task and the time it took for them to complete the task is noted. For each task, points are given to each competitor based on the order of their completion times. The fastest competitor gets N points, next fastest gets N-1 etc, the last competitor gets 1 point. The points are accumulated for a final tally from which a ranking is established.

Note in the event any two competitors complete in the same time, they are given equivalent points - In short ordinal ranking.

My problem is as follows, the tasks even though they are all equally important are not equally complex. Some tasks are more difficult than others. As a result what we observe is that the time difference between the 1st place and last place competitors can sometimes be 2-3 orders of magnitude. This situation is compounded when in scenarios the top M% competitors completes in a time that is 1-3 orders of magnitude less than the next best competitor.

I would like to somehow signify and make obvious these differences in the final ranking.

Is there such a ranking system that can accommodate such a requirement?

Comment: Say there are just two competitors, A and B, and ten tasks. If A is just one nanosecond faster than B on the first nine but a whole day slower than B on the tenth, would you still want A to be ranked best overall?

Answer (score 2):

Since your system is based on completion time, you obviously need to rank the complexity of each task by expected time. So each task needs to have a weight that you multiply N by so that the first place would get weight*N, second would get weight*(N-1). The final tally would sort the final weight ranking of each competitor and use that order as their final placement.

On the other hand, you may keep your system as it is now. Let a part of the competition be the wisdom of differentiating which task is more complex than another.